# What is the format of the django config file for manage.py?

Tags: django, selenium, configuration, manage.py

I'm hooking up selenose (selenium) tests and using liveserver in the process. It appears that I automatically start running into problems with ports being used so want to configure liveserver to use more that one port. I see how to do that via the command line (--liveserver=localhost:8100-8110) but would like to use a config file.

I have one I'm using for nose already and thought I might be able to reuse it but can't find anything to support that belief and my test runs say it won't work. I was expecting to be able to add something like the following:

[???]
liveserver=localhost:8100-8110

but replace the '???' with an actual header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for some reason django uses an environment variable for this. you can set it in your settings if you want

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_LIVE_TEST_SERVER_ADDRESS'] = 'localhost:8000-9000'
```

Comment: Great, this pointed me to the code and that is even what the default command does for --liveserver. I've added this to my settings.py, thanks!